# connect-redis in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, redis

I have nodejs/express/redis/express-session in use in my nodejs application (express 4.x)

The redis initializing is done by connect-redis/session framework under hood. So far it works.  Now I need to use redis to store other data in addition to session, and world like to have a new store other than the session store. Is it just one store possible?

And is it possible to use the redis client initialized by connect-redis/session if only one store is possible? how to get it?

Thanks for the help!

The code now is:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

// pass the express to the connect redis module
// allowing it to inherit from session.Store
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

....
// Populates req.session
app.use(session({
  resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
  saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  store: new RedisStore
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually want to initialize a new client for anything else, as the session library is handling it's own client under the hood.

You should most likely import the redis library itself, make your own client, and use that for all future requests / etc.

Answer (score 0):

When I put following code after the code above, I got error
"myRedis Error-> Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED". It seems it is not allowed to init a new Redis instance.

So is there a way to have new client from connect-redis?

```
var myRedis = require('redis');                           // additional redis store
var myRedisCli = myRedis.createClient();

myRedisCli.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('myRedis Error-> '  + err);
});
```